# AnkhSVN Newer Copy on Local

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, ankhsvn

I started to work on a project without setting it up for SVN .I am using Visual studio 2008 and AnkhSVN. Now I have new copy of code on my local and SVN has older copy.How should I checkout those files and commit them?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest is probably with the command line client (or TortoiseSvn with similar options). You're looking to do a checkout with the force flag on:

```
svn co --force <URL> <WC>
```

From the help:

```
If --force is used, unversioned obstructing paths in the working
copy destination do not automatically cause the check out to fail.
If the obstructing path is the same type (file or directory) as the
corresponding path in the repository it becomes versioned but its
contents are left 'as-is' in the working copy.  This means that an
obstructing directory's unversioned children may also obstruct and
become versioned.  For files, any content differences between the
obstruction and the repository are treated like a local modification
to the working copy.  All properties from the repository are applied
to the obstructing path.
```